# TypeError: bar() got multiple values for argument 'x'

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

I want to make a barplot and I am using this:

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = plt.bar(df_last_plot, y='Deaths', x='Country')
fig.update_layout(title='No.of Deaths for Top 10 Countries',
                   xaxis_title='Country',
                   yaxis_title='No.of Deaths Cases')
fig.show()
```

But it raised an error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-7f5e5e905f6e> in <module>
      1 import plotly.express as px
      2 
----> 3 fig = plt.bar(df_last_plot, y='Deaths', x='Country')
      4 fig.update_layout(title='No.of Deaths for Top 10 Countries',
      5                    xaxis_title='Country',

TypeError: bar() got multiple values for argument 'x'
```

My dataframe looks like:

df_last:

```
+-----------------+------------+
| Country         |  Deaths    |
+-----------------+------------+
|  Belgium        |  35312     |
|  France         |  167548    |
|  Germany        |  34001     |
|  Iran           |  88912     |
|  Italy          |  358872    | 
|  Mainland China |  192276    | 
|  Netherlands    |  35618     | 
|  Spain          |  253417    | 
|  UK             |  106910    | 
|  US             |  219105    |  
+-----------------+------------+
```

How to overcome that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) the function has the signature

```
matplotlib.pyplot.bar(x, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, \*, align='center', data=None,  \*\*kwargs)
```

As you can see `x` is the first argument, so calling the function as

```
fig = plt.bar(df_last_plot, y='Deaths', x='Country')
```

you are passing `df_last_plot` as `x` and then again as `'Country'`. 
I assume your intention was closer to the following

```
fig = plt.bar(df_last_plot['Country'], df_last_plot['Deaths'])
```